# How to use latest PHP with Apache

Tags: php, apache, osx-yosemite

I am using Yosemite and I want to configure Apache to use latest PHP (5.6). I have installed it through Homebrew but phpinfo says Apache still uses 5.5. How can I fix that? I googled but I didn't find nothing that helps me.

Answer (score 2):

why need to use apache + php on dev env when You've builtin webserver in php:

```
cd /path/to/public
php -S 127.0.0.1:8080
```

- about mysql: You can download and install it as service from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/file.php?id=458460

use brew tool (http://brew.sh/) to easily install necessary extensions to php

install it:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

run it:

```
brew install imagemagick
brew install php55-imagick
```

to update php:

```
brew tap homebrew/dupes
brew tap homebrew/versions
brew tap homebrew/homebrew-php
brew install php56
```

that's my dev environment, I do not install nginx, apache or etc to my local Mac, I do not see any real need of it.

Comment: That is a great info there! Thanks. Is it hard to upload it on a real server later which is on Apache?

Comment: of course it will work with apache + mod_php, nginx + php-fpm

Comment: feel free to ask questions to me in skype: anarjafarov

Comment: Does it work when you do url rewrites? i.e. clean urls which are based on `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRules` that are normally placed inside apache `.htaccess` file?

Comment: yes, in native php server rewrite is global rewrite to index.php file (no need to configure it), cuz most of php frameworks handling request to index.php. so rewriting like index.php$1 will work.

Comment: so you use clean urls and they work properly using the PHP built-in server?

Comment: I tried to use that builtin server but I got bunch of errors. I think I give up, I will install MAMP

Comment: I just found [this guide](http://gonzalo123.com/2012/10/15/how-to-rewrite-urls-with-php-5-4s-built-in-web-server/) to do url rewrites with builtin server you need to add an extra file and then point server there - not public dir

Comment: yes, see screenshots: http://joxi.ru/LVm6kkLCoa8j2Z   and this: http://joxi.ru/qVrwppXF9P31mX

Comment: yes, of course additional file is for development purposes, it gets env variables and makes $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to have normal data to make routing usual

Comment: mmm Im interested to use it - but I just cant figure out how to make the base URL that you inject into the HTML views,  e.g. that you inject into your link `HREF` and image `src` etc . In your screen shots the application looks like laravel 5 - which uses some call like `asset('url')` to inject for you - I dont use laravel - Im using native PHP and have to set a base URL  - cant work out how  I can get that to work with PHP builtin server - but looks promising!

Comment: use right tool, to quickly get things done. good luck in Your job (:

Comment: cool , thanks for sharing about the inbuilt server - could save some time for sure !

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out somehow.

I followed this tut -> http://blog.kicaj.com/installing-and-configuring-php-5-5-using-macports/

It seems to be working now. I have just used 56 instead of 55 in the commands.